# VB6 not recognizing ADODB enumerators via COM

Tags: com, vb6, enumerator

I am supporting a legacy ASP page which creates an ADODB stream object like this, then attempts to set it's type with an ADODB enumerator.

```
Set BinaryStream = Server.CreateObject("ADODB.Stream")
BinaryStream.Type = adTypeBinary
```

Whenever I run this I get the following error:

```
Variable is undefined: 'adTypeBinary'
```

However, if I explicitly name my enumerator, like this, it works

```
 BinaryStream.Type = ADODB.StreamTypeEnum.adTypeBinary
```

This is running on several instances of servers, which are theoretically all in sync in terms of configuration and files and such. This works on all the servers except one, and I'm not sure what we did to have this start happening. I can confirm this is happening to at least one other library we use. What is going on here? Thanks!

Comment: I haven't used VB6 or ASP in a long time. But I presume you have adovbs.inc somewhere on your servers. Check if that changed or was removed on the one that's having issues.

Comment: I checked and that file is in 4 places, (Program Files\Common FIles\System\ado and winsxs\some stuff). The 64 and 32 bit versions of both of those. How can I make sure they're being loaded successfully/unsuccessfully?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

AFAIK outside of an external include that defines those values, the only way that you can use unqualified members like that is to define a typelib reference in your global.asa:

```
<!--METADATA TYPE="typelib" 
NAME="Microsoft ActiveX Data Objects 2.8 Library" 
UUID="{2A75196C-D9EB-4129-B803-931327F72D5C}" 
VERSION="2.8"-->
```